# Codeigniter: store user login and logouts times

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter v3. I want to store user login and logout times. When user login, store login time and when logout button is clicked, update user record in table. This scenario is good when he/she clicked on loggout button.

But there are two problem if clicking not happened:

1. when session expired (after 2 hours)
2. when closed browser window/tab

for first problem, in the next login, I add 2 hours to last login time and update last record (not current record). But this is not precise, because user may reload and extend session expiration time. for example: user login at 5:30 p.m. and during 2 next hours reload pages many times and extend session expiration.

If last reload is at 8:00 p.m., the session will expired at 10:00 p.m., but I stored 7:30 pm. for logout time! and for second, nothing!

Any help and guide about these problems will be appreciated...

Comment: rename `logged_out` column to `last_seen`. update this column whenever the user does anything

Answer (score 1):

- Add another datetime field called something like session_timeactive_last 
  Then every time a logged in user does anything - including when they first log in - you log the time in that field. 
  .
- create a script that runs say every 15 minutes. it first checks the field 
  session_logout_time and if there is a value ignores that record. if there is not a value then it looks in session_timeactive_last . if that value is more then two hours old, then it adds 2 hours to the value from  session_timeactive_last and writes that to session_logout_time